# How the page --yotube.com/channels-- load their links?

Tags: python, html, youtube-api

I'm trying to get the subscribed channels list on `youtube.com/anyuser/channels`. Using python, it is possible to get just some of them (apparently the API return 6 by default). When you open the page, YouTube load the first 10 and more 10 every time you scroll down.
I just want to understand how does it work: YouTube save these channels links in another page, and pull them every time you scroll? Since YouTube considers this public information, is there a way to get all the channel, or force YouTube to load them?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that when you say that "apparently the API return 6 by default", you mean 5 as documented in [Subscriptions: list#maxResults](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#maxResults).
Its max value is 50.

By fetching https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&maxResults=50&key=YOUR_API_KEY by using [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) you can quickly retrieve all `youtube.com/anyuser/channels`.

Example of channel id having a not empty channels tab: [UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ)